# C++:creating default constructor for a class that owns a class member(the member lacks default constructor)

Tags: c++

The problem is based on c++ primer 5th edition 7.43.

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class C;
    class NoDefault{
    friend class C;
    public:
        NoDefault(int a) :item(a) {}   //lack default constructor
    private:
        int item;
    };
    class C{
    public:
        C() :item(1){}  //default constructor
        void print();
    private:
        NoDefault item;
    };
    void C::print()
    {
        cout<<item.item;
    }
    int main()
    {
        C obj1;
        obj1.print();
        return 0;
    }
```

The excecution of the program display no output and just ends directly.
I think the output should be 1,because the following initializing process:

```
    C() :item(1){}  //default constructor
    NoDefault(int a) :item(a) {}
```

Please point out my mistake,many thanks!

Comment: I got result 1 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6496099be390c182

Comment: If you determine "no output" while debugging (not a rare event, especially with Visual Studio as it closes the console window on program termination, conveniently allowing you a mere fraction of a second to witness `stdout` flush on shutdown) , perhaps flush the output stream along with that write:  `std::cout << item.item << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help from people who answered my question! The code I posted was correct and the problem is something wrong with my compiler...